# How to split string into 2 variables using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to split a field with an abundance of text into 2 variables, display one in one section of the page and then carry on with the remainder of the field in another spot. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the input. I have no delimiter available as the user inputs the text via FCKeditor. Is it possible to get the length of the inputted text, insert a special character and then use as a delimiter? It is presented as a story, with one page having a certain height and the other page continuing the story much like a book. Here's what the query looks like:

```
$query = "select * from tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results !="0")
{
    echo "<table class='style1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
        echo $description;
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: What are the criteria for where to split?

Comment: Is there some delimeter you can split the text by, or does one variable have to be a certain length? Or, how do plan on identifying where to split the text at?

Comment: Please provide further detail such as example input and output expected

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact requirements, either `explode()` or `substr()` should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$data = explode($delimiter,$sql["field"]);

echo $data[0];

...

echo $data[1];
```

Something like this?

Comment: You're missing `$` signs for `$data[0];` and `$data[1];`, and, it may be appropriate to use, `explode($delimiter, $sql["field"], 2);` so as to guarantee no more than 2 elements in `$data`.... though it's hard to tell from the question if using the limit would be helpful.

Comment: I edited it, though I'm pretty sure I typed it :\
An example text would be nice, for now this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the maximum amount of text is which can go into each 'page' of your 'book' - e.g. 500 characters? What you could do is break at the last suitable point before the 500-character limit (e.g. the last space, or the last full stop).

It will be fairly straightforward to do that with a few standard php string functions:

- substr (to take the first 500 characters)
- strrpos  (to find the last space/full stop/whatever in those 500 characters)